# Should we store business entites in viewstate variable

Tags: asp.net, session, viewstate, state-management

I have a business entity, which I use on a single aspx page. This page has many controls and hence a lot of postbacks will happen.
I want to know, Is it advisable to store this business entity in viewstate(because I need it on a single page) or Session(because if the entity has more data it will increase my page size and hence network latency).

Answer (score 0):

**View State:**

Why do you use ViewState? It makes your page heavier. Hence you will end up with poor response time.

**Session -** From my view, you can use it here but make sure you remove it once it is not necessary or no longer referred. As you start storing objects in Session IIS will store those in in-memory/in proc (default) will get increased and IIS processing will be slower over the period of time. If your server has good memory 32GB Ram and other capabilities to handle , you no need to worry

**HttpContext**

HttpContext would be the much better way of storing an object between a single round trip(request/response). So you can prefer this over a session as it will be availble only for a current request, no need to worry about removing an object like session handling, as it will be automatically cleared once the request completed.

Hope these things would be helpful to you!